# Using getter-setter for a variable after it gets a value from an API call

Tags: ios, swift, getter-setter

I have a function like so..

```
@IBAction func btn_Login(_ sender: Any) {

        AuthenticateAndGoToMainScreen()

}
```

Now in the `AuthenticateAndGoToMainScreen()` method there is an API call where I get a `token`. Now when I get a token I want to navigate to another screen. I can't do that within the API call since it throws an error that `performWithSegue` can only be accessed in main thread.

Giving `performWithSegue` in main thread also doesn't work because when I navigate to the next screen and click on a button, it crashes.

So I would like to have something like this..

```
@IBAction func btn_Login(_ sender: Any) {

        AuthenticateAndGoToMainScreen()
        if mytoken != "" {

         performSegueWithIdentifier..... 
        } 

}
```

In this case, I get the token in the result of the API call. But my doubt is..how can I know if the value of the variable `mytoken` has changed and so my control will come back again to the `btn_Login` function and then do  `performSegueWith...`.

This can be achieved with `getter-setter` I feel..But I'm not sure how to implement that here...

Comment: myToken { didSet { do smth } }

Comment: Consider that the workflow won't work anyway if the API call is asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

Use property observer didSet and call the performSegue.. on main thread. Something like :

```
var myToken: String {
  didSet {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.performSegue(...)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple way you can do this, but simples would be by having a `didSet` on `myToken` like so:

```
var myToken: String {
  didSet {
    performSegueWithIdentifier
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This logic is impossible:

```
AuthenticateAndGoToMainScreen ()
if mytoken != "" {
```

If AuthenticateAndGoToMainScreen is doing networking, then the networking takes time. It is asynchronous. It will finish *after* the second line! So the token will not be ready yet and the `if` will fail.

Your logic can only operate through a chain of asynchronous callbacks or a Combine-type pipeline. Your response to getting the token must be triggered from within AuthenticateAndGoToMainScreen itself.